# MySQL read speed of C# application way too long

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So I have an MySQL table which needs to be read out entirely by a C# application. The table holds about 1200 records.
When I read out this table using the MySQL Workbench it takes about 0,047seconds.
The server I'm reading on is on a raspberry pi but that doesn't seem to be the problem because the Workbench can read out from it fast enough.

When I try to read out this table using my C# application, it takes about 5 minutes :-/.

Is there a better way to read out the table?

Here's my code:

```
private void ReadOut()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = null;
    MySqlCommand cmd = null;
    MySqlDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, EPC, Tijd, Binnen, custcol1, custcol2 FROM " + _strTableName + ";", conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        _oDataTable.Clear();
        _oBindingsource.DataSource = _oDataTable;
        if(this.OpenConnection(conn))
        {
            using(reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                _oDataTable.Load(reader);                       
            }                   
        }
        _oBindingsource.Sort = "Tijd DESC";
        if (fInitialized == false)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
            fInitialized = true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        tmrUpdate.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null) reader.Close();
        if (conn != null) conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Regardless of whether Raberry Pi is good, fast etc. - unless columns contain lots of data, 5 minutes is outrageous.

Comment: hum, 1200 entries, that is essentially nothing, could it be that your grid refreshing and event thingies slow it down? Did you try to comment those parts out so that you only have the plain querying of the database in your c# code? (i.e. pretty much all lines involving `_oDataTable`, `_oBindingsource` and `this.dataGridView1`)

Comment: why don't you alter the query and add a filter.. then see if the data response is the same.. also I wonder if you have some very poor indexing going on in that table..

Comment: this is an issue as well `_oBindingsource.DataSource = _oDataTable;` why not assign this after the query execution has completed.. and since you are not really doing anything with the data why don't you use the `Fill()

Comment: I read that the mysqldatareader was more efficient to get data from the db than the mysqldataadapter for "SELECT ..." queries

Comment: Ok so I commented out `_oBindingsource.DataSource = _oDataTable;` and  `_oBindingsource.Sort = "Tijd DESC";`  and now there is no hangup anymore. So it appears that binding the Datatable to the Datagridview is the time consuming part here... any suggestions?

Comment: That sounds like a new question.